# twitter search api v1.1 - TwitterException{exceptionCode=

Tags: android

My application is authenticated with Twitter, and returns control to my application. But when it comes to the search for tweets I get the following error:

```
No authentication challenges found  Relevant discussions can be
> found on the Internet at:     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5
> or    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=12c94143 
> TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-12c94143 43208640-465ee2e3],
> statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1,
> rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}      at
> twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192)
>   at
> twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
>   at
> twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
>   at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1835)     at
> twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:282)    at
> com.leccion.herencia.Alar$5.run(Alar.java:239)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)  Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> No authentication challenges found    at
> libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
>   at
> libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
>   at
> libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
> at
> libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
```

Y el codigo de mi app es:

```
final Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();  
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken); 
            final Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j api"); 

             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                     
                        try {

         result = twitter.search(query); ***//el error en esta linea!!!***

                             for (Status status : result.getTweets())
                             {
                                    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going thru this same issue. You need to also set your access token and token secret. Its listed in your twitter app on twitter website along with your consumer key and secret. So 4 total to set. I got it working after that.

I have a question about how to use v1.1 api by manually constructing the link and parsing the json myself rather than using a library. No tutorials explain how to do this.

Comment: I register on twitter and I have the 4 keys, I made ​​my app calls a url to utenticarme and call me back, but when running the code that gives me the error show that show.

For the api 1.0 I was able to get the tweets, but for this version I could and have not found anything on the internet worth.